# How can I get the href attribute value out of an <?xml-stylesheet> node?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

We are getting an XML document from a vendor that we need to perform an XSL transform on using their stylesheet so that we can convert the resulting HTML to a PDF.  The actual stylesheet is referenced in an `href` attribute of the `?xml-stylesheet` definition in the XML document.  Is there any way that I can get that URL out using C#?  I don't trust the vendor not to change the URL and obviously don't want to hardcode it.

The start of the XML file with the full `?xml-stylesheet` element looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.fakeurl.com/StyleSheet.xsl"?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to xml code:

```
XDocument xDoc = ...;

var cssUrlQuery = from node in xDoc.Nodes()
        where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction
        select Regex.Match(((XProcessingInstruction)node).Data, "href=\"(?<url>.*?)\"").Groups["url"].Value;
```

or linq to objects

```
var cssUrls = (from XmlNode childNode in doc.ChildNodes
                   where childNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction && childNode.Name == "xml-stylesheet"
                   select (XmlProcessingInstruction) childNode
                   into procNode select Regex.Match(procNode.Data, "href=\"(?<url>.*?)\"").Groups["url"].Value).ToList();
```

xDoc.XPathSelectElement() will not work since it for some reasone cannot cast an XElement to XProcessingInstruction.

Comment: I would prefer to use the DOM or LinqToXml, but the more I dig the more it looks like this might be the only option.

Comment: Yea, I've been struggling with that, too.  If there were some way I could treat the ProcessingInstruction like an Element, it would be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

As a processing instruction can have any contents it formally does not have any attributes. But if you know there are "pseudo" attributes, like in the case of an xml-stylesheet processing instruction, then you can of course use the value of the processing instruction to construct the markup of a single element and parse that with the XML parser:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"file.xml");
    XmlNode pi = doc.SelectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')");
    if (pi != null)
    {
        XmlElement piEl = (XmlElement)doc.ReadNode(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("<pi " + pi.Value + "/>")));
        string href = piEl.GetAttribute("href");
        Console.WriteLine(href);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No pi found.");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  It took a long time to figure out these are called "processing-instructions", and LINQ still doesn't make any sense to me!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use XPath. Given an XmlDocument loaded with your source:

```
XmlProcessingInstruction instruction = doc.SelectSingleNode("//processing-instruction(\"xml-stylesheet\")") as XmlProcessingInstruction;
if (instruction != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(instruction.InnerText);
}
```

Then just parse InnerText with Regex.

Comment: Using this XPATH expression and you don't need to do any Regex: `translate(substring-after(processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet'),'href='),'&quot;','')`

Answer (score 2):

To find the value using a proper XML parser you could write something like this:

```
using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(input))
{
    while(xr.Read())
    {
        if(xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction && xr.Name == "xml-stylesheet")
        {
            string s = xr.Value;
            int i = s.IndexOf("href=\"") + 6;
            s = s.Substring(i, s.IndexOf('\"', i) - i);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When using the XmlReader approach, be aware that method calls like `IsStartElement` will cause the reader to skip over processing instructions if the start element node is found. I used a separate read loop to parse the processing instructions before parsing the element nodes as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
private string _GetTemplateUrl(XDocument formXmlData) 
{
    var infopathInstruction = (XProcessingInstruction)formXmlData.Nodes().First(node => node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction && ((XProcessingInstruction)node).Target == "mso-infoPathSolution");
    var instructionValueAsDoc = XDocument.Parse("<n " + infopathInstruction.Data + " />");
    return instructionValueAsDoc.Root.Attribute("href").Value;
}
```

Comment: One has to use `xml-stylesheet` instead of `mso-infoPathSolution`, but then it works for me. It takes the first element and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

XmlProcessingInstruction stylesheet = doc.SelectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')") as XmlProcessingInstruction;