# ASP.NET MVC 3 Parse simple html tag/extract attribute value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What is the best way to parse html tag like that:

```
<a href="/Results">Results</a>
```

i just need to extract a href value.

I need to do this on controller.

I know i may use `linq to xml` for example or `regex`.

Any ideas what is the better way for that case?

May be there is any MVC helpers ready to go?

Basically what i need to do:

I have my extension method witch returning current url

```
public static string GetCurrentUrl(this ViewContext context)
        {
            string action = (string)context.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue;
            string controller = (string)context.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue;

            if (action.ToLower() != "index")
                return String.Format("/{0}/{1}", controller, action);
            else if (action.ToLower() != "index" && controller.ToLower() != "home")
                return String.Format("/{0}", controller);
            else
                return "/";
        }
```

I need to compare this url with the value from a href like that `<a href="{here cold be any link}">Results</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a XML parser and avoid regex. For this specific case [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) seems easy enough:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<a href=\"/Results\">Results</a>");
var href = doc.Element("a").Attribute("href").Value;
```

For more complex scenarios when HTML specific parsing is required and manipulating the DOM you could use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: is it would be right way(answer for that question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119699/how-can-i-get-the-href-attribute-value-out-of-an-xml-stylesheet-node

Comment: I need to do this only once and wouldn't reference HTML Agility Pack just for that simple small thing.

Comment: @Joper, no, the accepted answer isn't the best way for me. It is the comment this [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119699/how-can-i-get-the-href-attribute-value-out-of-an-xml-stylesheet-node/2120022#2120022) which doesn't involve any regex the correct way.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is it safe to use an XML parser for HTML? Since HTML is not compliant to XML, for instance the `disabled` attribute, or unclosed `<input>`, `<hr>`, and `<p>` etc. elements?

Answer (score 0):

parsing html is notoriously difficult, there are so many hidden gotchas. The [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which is a .NET HTML parsing library.   [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) enables css selectors for html in c# and is built on top of the agility pack.