# Exception while reading XML - "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed"

Tags: c#, xml

My xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../config/janes-deliver.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE janes:record SYSTEM "../../config/janesml-delivery-norm-2.1.dtd">
<janes:record xmlns:janes="http://dtd.janes.com/2002/Content/" id="j1891356689831320" pubabbrev="JIQ" sysId="JIQ0105" urname="record">
<janes:metadata xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="j1891356689831320" urname="metadata" xlink:type="simple">
<dc:rights xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Copyright © IHS Global Limited, 2014</dc:rights>
<dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" qualifier="pubDate">30000101</dc:date>
<dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" qualifier="postDate">20140822</dc:date>
<janes:title urname="title">IHS Jane's Navigating the Emerging Markets</janes:title>
<janes:shortTitle urname="shortTitle">Canada</janes:shortTitle>
<janes:sect1 id="j18967561358768718373" urname="sect1">
<janes:para id="j18967561358768718388" urname="para"><janes:link xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="jiq0105_a.pdf" qualifier="pdf" urname="link" xlink:type="simple"><janes:linkText urname="linkText">Please click here for the full PDF report.</janes:linkText></janes:link></janes:para>
</janes:sect1>
<janes:sect1 id="j26330201380885096083" updated="y" urname="sect1">
<janes:title urname="title">Military inventories</janes:title>
.......................
```

I need to retrieve the contents of the tag

I have written a code like below

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);


foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("janes:link"))
{
    string name = node.Name;
    string value = node.InnerText;
    // ...
}
```

I am getting the error "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

Can Some one help ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("janes", "http://dtd.janes.com/2002/Content/");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes(@"//janes:link", nsmgr))
{
    //...
}
```

This [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178111/why-is-xmlnamespacemanager-necessary) explains why `XmlNamespaceManager` is needed.

Comment: Thanks . How will I retrieve value in xlink:href  of xml ?

Comment: You can find declaration nodes in this way `doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlProcessingInstruction>()` and then parse `XmlProcessingInstruction.Value` property which in your case will return _type="text/xsl" href="../../config/janes-deliver.xsl"_ See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119699/how-can-i-get-the-href-attribute-value-out-of-an-xml-stylesheet-node)